# Copy Customer Group and Group Price

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-group, group-price

I am trying to add a new Customer Group and copy the price of one of the Group Price's products into this new customer group for all products. For example, I have a customer group Group1 which has price x, and I want to create a script which adds the new group (Group2) and copies the price from Group1 (x) to all products. Has anyone done this before/can point me in the right direction?

I'm starting by trying to load group prices, but it returns empty:

```
    function productCallback($args)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->setData($args['row']);
    echo $args['arg1'] . "\n";  
    echo $product->getSku() . ': ' . $product->getName() . "<br/>";

    $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
    foreach($groupPrices as $key)
    {
        foreach($key as $subkey => $value)
        {
            echo $subkey . " ~ " . $value . "<br/>";
        }
    }

    echo "<br/><br/>";
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($products->getSelect(), array('productCallback'), array('arg1' => '===='));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
require_once("./app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

function productCallback($args)
{
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    echo $product->getSku() . ': ' . $product->getGroupPrice() . "<br/>";

    $groupPrices = $product->getData('group_price');
    $standardWholesalePrice = 0;
    foreach($groupPrices as $key=>$value)
    {
        foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue)
        {
            if ($subkey == "cust_group" && $subvalue == 2) 
            {
                $standardWholesalePrice = $value['price'];
                $newGroupPrice = array(array ( 'website_id'=>1,
                'cust_group'=>5,
                'price'=>$standardWholesalePrice,
                'website_price'=>$standardWholesalePrice,
                'all_groups'=>0));

                $newGroupPrices = array_merge($groupPrices,$newGroupPrice);

                $product->setData('group_price',$newGroupPrices);
                $product->save();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<br/><br/>";
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')                        
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('group_price'));

Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($products->getSelect(), array('productCallback'), array('arg1' => '===='));
```